# JavaScript remove array with empty elements inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I run an process that generates an array of arrays. But sometimes it will generate an array with empty elements

```
[
 [1,'a','b'],
 [2,'b','c'],
 [3,'c','d'],
 ['', '', ''],
 ['', '', ''],
]
```

I need remove those arrays. I tried using filter function

```
array.filter(el => el !== '');
```

But doesn't work. Also try different ways with for or foreach loop, but nothing.

Comment: `arr.filter(subarr => subarr.some(Boolean))`

Comment: In your example `el` is an array, so you cannot compare it with empty string, instead (if all of elements are empty), you may check whether first item of `el` is empty (i.e. do `el[0]!==''`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if all elements of a subarray are empty strings:

```js
const array = [
 [1,'a','b'],
 [2,'b','c'],
 [3,'c','d'],
 ['', '', ''],
 ['', '', ''],
];

const filtered = array.filter(a => !a.every(el => el === ''));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: A negated `.every` is equivalent to a `.some` with a negated condition. This could be written using the equivalent: `const filtered = array.filter(a => a.some(el => el !== ''));`, or since empty strings are falsy anyway: `const filtered = array.filter(a => a.some(Boolean));`.

Comment: @CRice you are right about `.every` and `.some` but `a.some(Boolean)` will also filter out any arrays that contain only falsey elements like `[0, false, null]`

Comment: A good point, it is just so. Using the `Boolean` function makes the snippet shorter, but it is not exactly equivalent to before, as you describe. *Caveat Emptor*.

Answer (score 0):

Does *array* refer to the multidimensional array itself? If so, then *el* would refer to each 1D array element within the 2D array.  No array is equal to '' so this won't work.
Try using *map* to access each 1D array and call filter on each of those.

```
array.map(arr => arr.filter(el => el !== ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const arr = 
[
 [1,'a','b'],
 [2,'b','c'],
 [3,'c','d'],
 ['', '', ''],
 ['', '2', ''],
];

const res = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
    const value = c.filter(v => v !== '');
    if (value.length > 0) {
 a.push(value);
    }
    return a;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```